# No such module 'EVReflection'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

New to XCode & iOS dev. Got "No such module '[EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection)'" trying to import and use EVReflection. I have inited and installed pods. Here is my "pod install" output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using EVReflection (4.8.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

Here is my PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myproject' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod "EVReflection"

  target 'myprojectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'myprojectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you installed your Pods, close xCode. Then open it back using the following command line:

> $ open App.xcworkspace

Clean your project then build project and it will work as expected. Finally, you can access it properties

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I wish XCode can be smarter about this though.